# How can I decrease the image uploading time when using multer(nodejs multer) and AWS S3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image-uploading, aws-sdk, multer

I am hongkevin developing one service for photographers and models by using Node.js, MongoDB, and AWS.

For developing the photo upload function, I am using three modules such as multer, multer-s3, aws-sdk. The process is as followed.

1. Getting single image and related information from the client.
2. Upload it to AWS s3 by using multer.
3. Fint out whether the user is model or photographer.
4. Save the file information including the image url.

Unfortunately, I found that when uploading the image, it takes time from 1 second to 5 seconds.

Therefore, I want you to let me know how to decrease the time-consumption(how to give client the result within short time).

Thanks. My code is as followed.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var db = require('../models/db');
require('../models/bookmodel');
require('../models/usermodel');
var BookModel = db.model('Book');
var UserModel = db.model('User');

// 이미지 업로드 셋팅
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1';
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3 : s3,
    bucket : 'mocatest',
    acl : 'public-read',
    key : function(req, file, callback) {
      var tmp = file.mimetype.split('/')[1]; // file.mimetype
      if (tmp == 'jpeg') { tmp = 'jpg' }
      var ext = "." + tmp;
      var keyword = "Moca_Photo_";
      var newname = keyword + Date.now().toString() + ext;
      callback(null, newname);
    }
  })
});

// 3-11. Uploading a book(사진 업로드하기)
router.post('/', upload.single('img'), function(req, res, next) {
  var token_user_id = req.decoded.user_id;

  // imgSave function start
  var imgSave = function() {
    var book_img = req.file.location;
    var book_desc = req.body.book_desc;

    var data = new BookModel({
      user_id   : token_user_id,
      book_img  : book_img,
      book_desc : book_desc
    });

    data.save(function(err, docs) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json({ success: 1, message: "photo is uploaded" });
    });
  };
  // imgSave function end

  UserModel.findOne({ user_id: token_user_id }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (docs.user_type == "M" || docs.user_type == "P") {
      imgSave();
    } else {
      res.json({ success: 0, message: "You should be registered as a model or photographer first" });
    }
  });
});
```